# Creating JP2 rasters with FWTools

Tags: fwtools, jpeg-2000

I have been trying to make JP2 raster files with FWTools with limited success.  FWTools will not allow for the creation of a JP2 file at a specific file size.  However, I am able to make a JP2 with the same data within ArcMap.  Is there a file size limit with FWTools?  Does anyone know of any work arounds?  I am looking to make larger sized GeoTiffs (100+ MB) into JP2 files.

Thanks...

Comment: By FWTools do you mean gdal_translate?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  When I use gdal_translate and try to convert raster files to JP2 I have limitations based in sizes of the output file.

Comment: The ECW based driver does have a file size limit.  Did it give you any error messages?  http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2ecw.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this response is 6 months late, but you could use the development build found here - [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) or you could build your own. In order to accomplish what you are wanting to do without obtaining a third party encoding sdk, you will need the OpenJPEG library (v2) library - http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2openjpeg.html

Comment: It is 6 months late, but still very valid.  Thank you.